# Inversing badly-conditioned square matrix: methodology

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a badly-conditioned square matrix. I need to inverse it. For inversing, currently I'm doing the following steps:

- I take the badly-conditioned matrix with size of $n$ by $n$
- By reduced row echelon form (RREF) I find $r$ linearly-independent columns of badly-conditioned matrix (I have to choose an appropriate tolerance for RREF). After RREF, I know the index of columns and rows which are linearly independent.
- I keep a $r$ by $r$ matrix which contains only linearly-independent columns and rows.
- I inverse the $r$ by $r$ matrix with *Cholesky Decomposition* (if symmetric positive definite: $A A^{-1}=I$ then $LL^{T}A^{-1}=I$ then $A^{-1}=...$) or *LU Decomposition* ($AA^{-1}=I$ then $LUA^{-1}=I$ then $A^{-1}=...$).
- Then I have the inverse which is a $r$ by $r$ matrix
- I create a $n$ by $n$ matrix which is all zeros.
- I move the elements of $r$ by $r$ inverse matrix to $n$ by $n$ zero matrix based on the fact that I know index of linearly dependent columns and rows from previous steps.
- Finally, I have a $n$ by $n$ matrix which can be inverse of the original badly-conditioned $n$ by $n$ matrix.

My first question: is the above methodology correct?

My second question: is there any better methodology (faster and more precise)?

Comment: how large is $n$? is this a theoretical or a practical question, and if practical: what software are you using?

Comment: @user66081 My $n$ is around 823 to 1044. My software is MATLAB or GNU Octave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is certainly incorrect, as it produces a matrix of rank $r$ rather than $n$, and this can't be the inverse of anything.

You might want to look into the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse, which produces something like what you're calculating.  Again, you can't call this 
"the inverse" of your matrix, but for some purposes it can be used instead of an inverse.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study on Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse.

Comment: Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse worked! Now my code generates expected results in MATLAB / GNU Octave.